How to reconcile these statements in my linear algebra text?
I'm having a hard time reconciling these statements written in my linear algebra text.

The necessary and sufficient condition for a set of vectors $S$ to be linearly dependent is that one vector in $S$ is a linear combination of the other vectors in $S$.
If a set of vectors $S$ contains vector $\theta$, then $S$ is linearly dependent.
The set $S = \{v\}$ is linearly independent if and only if $v \neq \theta$.

I understand that statement $(1)$ follows from the definition of linear dependence (that a set is linearly dependent if there exists a non-trivial combination of its vectors that equals $\theta$).
Suppose $S$ is linearly dependent and WLOG suppose that $\alpha_n \neq 0$ in $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i = \theta$. Then we have $v_n = -\sum\limits_{i =1}^{n-1}\dfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_n}v_i,$ which shows that $v_n$ is a linear combination of the other vectors in $S$. On the other hand, if we have $v_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \lambda_i v_i$, then it follows that $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n-1} \lambda_i v_i - v_{n} = \theta$.
Statement $(1)$ in its current phrasing clearly holds when $S$ contains more than one element, as shown. When $S = \{v\}$, I'd consider "$v$ is a linear combination of the other vectors in S" satisfied as there are no "other vectors" in the set, so the statement holds vacuously and $S = \{1\}$ is linearly dependent by this reasoning. However, this conclusion contradicts statement $(3)$.
So my question is, is statement $(1)$ true for all sets $S$? If so, how to properly interpret it for situations when $S$ contains only one element?
Thank you very much!

Just a comment on the notation, I don't think I ever see $\theta$ stands for zero vector. In many books it's just $\mathbf{0}$.

@Tri There are textbooks that use $\theta$ for the zero vector, but it is not in English.

@Tri Yes, like Duong said, my text uses $\theta$ for vector 0.

@ten_to_tenth I understand that people have their own notations, but my point is it doesn't seem to be a usual one. I would suggest a note on the notation though. On the other hand, I think the answer to your question can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3659517/how-do-i-prove-that-a-set-containing-only-one-vector-is-linearly-independent

"When $S = {v}$, I'd consider "$v$ is a linear combination of the other vectors in S" satisfied as there are no "other vectors" in the set, so the statement holds vacuously and $S = {1}$ is linearly dependent by this reasoning." No. You're correct that there are no other vectors in the set. Then the condition becomes that $v$ has to be a linear combination of no vectors, i.e. an empty linear combination, which is the zero vector.

Yes. Statement 1 is true for all sets of vectors $S$.
If $S$ has exactly one element $v$, the set of vectors in $S$ other than $v$ is the empty set. Let's look closer to the statement:

The necessary and sufficient condition for a set of vectors $S$ to be linearly dependent is that one vector in $S$ is a linear combination of the other vectors in $S$.

To resolve the issue of the singleton sets, we need to know what the linear combination of no vector means. Fortunately, there is already a definition: "the span of the empty list of vectors is defined to be $\{ \theta \}$", see Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right (4th edition), section 2A.

Let's verify for the case $S = \{ v \}$

If $v \ne \theta$ then any linear combination of the vectors in $S$ other than $v$ is $\theta$, and $v \ne \theta$. So $S$ is linearly independent.
If $v = \theta$ then it is a linear combination of the vectors in $S$ other than $v$, due to the above definition. So $S$ is linearly dependent.


That extra definition is contained in my text but I never understood its significance when I first read it. Your comment has fully resolved my confusion. Thank you very much!

If a vector $v$ is a linear combination of zero vectors, then $v=0$, since one usually understands an empty sum to be zero; if $v=0$, then $v$ is a linear combination of zero vectors - for similar reasons.
